# Typescript keyof type change based on number of keys

Tags: typescript

I have a library that exposes an interface. I'm using the `keyof` feature to add a type to a function parameter. By default, the interface is empty. **Users can extend this interface (module augmentation)**.

Is there any way to change the type to `any` if the interface doesn't contain any keys?

```
interface A {}

function test(a: keyof A) {}


test('anyType') // here it should be `any`
```

```
interface A {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

function test(a: keyof A) {}


test('name') // here it should be `id | name`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `A` doesn't have properties `keyof A` resolves to `never`. So, you can use [Conditional Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#conditional-types) here, like:

```js
function test(a: keyof A extends never ? any : keyof A) {}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=2&ssc=59&pln=2&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4F8BQMCuICYwA9iMpAM5gAUcAXMgNYQCepMayEAHpCAAmVZCAgA3aMgD8yOCDbImrDl1QBKTLmp0A5PLYAVNgAcIuzQHpLyABbQUwMMiq3S%20ADaDkAIxQADA38gA)